# Magento Filter products by rating

Tags: magento-1.9

Is it possible to add **rating filter** on product listing filter ?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

This tutorial explains how create a custom filter in Layered Navigation: [`http://www.techytalk.info/create-custom-layered-navigation-filter-magento/`](http://www.techytalk.info/create-custom-layered-navigation-filter-magento/)

http://www.netismine.com/magento/sort-product-list-by-rating

A paid is extension also available:
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ratings-filter-and-sort.html

Comment: try this.. 
https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/Custom-product-filter/td-p/40425